# Kusto Purge Permissions/Malformed Query

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql

I am running into issues with executing the .purge command within Azure Data Explorer (Kusto).

Command:

`.purge table myTable records <| where MyColumn == 'ColumnName'`

Results in a

`Error Principal 'aaduser=[ID]' is not authorized to perform operation 'PurgeTableRecordsCommand' on 'https://[cluster url]/'. clientRequestId: KustoWebV2;[ID]`

Also running the example from : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/kusto/concepts/data-purge

`.purge table myTable records in database myDB <| where MyColumn in ('column1')`

Results in a

`Error Syntax error: Query could not be parsed:`

I have checked with Access Control (IAM) on the cluster resource and contacted Azure team about my role/permissions and have Contributor role on the cluster and Database Admin role on the database.

Comment: you should be using the 2nd flavor from your example against the data management service - https://ingest-<cluster-name>.<region>.kusto.windows.net. Is this what you are doing? (see the note here - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/kusto/concepts/data-purge#trigger-the-purge-process).

Comment: Got it that was the issue, also needed to open a support ticket in order to enable the EnabledForPurge flag. Thank you @yifats

Comment: You can also enable the Purge feature through the ADX configuration blade. Now it is available to the public.